# How to make a wpf MediaElement play when its Source is a https uri

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception, mediaelement

In a wpf standalone application (.exe) I have included a MediaElement in the MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="Media.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Main Window" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Player" Stretch="Uniform" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and from the code behind I set its `Source` to any https Uri:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var source = new Uri("https://stream_which_can_be_opened_with_windows_media_player.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        Player.Source = source;
        Player.Play();
    }
}
```

When the `Play()` method is called a `NullReferenceException` is thrown instead of playing the media content. `MediaElement` is initialized, the `NullReferenceException` is thrown from the `Play()` method, see below.

The same Uri for the video can be opened in Windows Media Player (File->Open Url).

The issue seems to be in `MediaPlayerState.OpenMedia` method (an object which the `MediaElement` uses internally) which tries to check if appDeploymentUri retrieved from `SecurityHelper.ExtractUriForClickOnceDeployedApp` has the scheme HTTPS. The application is not deployed with `ClickOnce` (it has a standalone installer) and the appDeploymentUri is null, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

This is from PresentationFramework.dll, System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.OpenMedia

```
    if (SecurityHelper.AreStringTypesEqual(uriToOpen.Scheme, Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
    {
        // target is HTTPS. Then, elevate ONLY if we are NOT coming from HTTPS (=XDomain HTTPS app to HTTPS media disallowed)

        //source of the issue
        Uri appDeploymentUri = SecurityHelper.ExtractUriForClickOnceDeployedApp();
        //appDeploymentUri is null
        if (!SecurityHelper.AreStringTypesEqual(appDeploymentUri.Scheme, Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
```

Does anyone have any about a workaround/solution to make it work?

Comment: Strange and ugly bug I've also discovered today. Did upvote and re report your issue at MS.

Comment: If you add the link to the bug report I will up vote it.

Comment: It's actually your own bug report. You've posted it in a comment to the accepted answer. ;-)

Comment: FYI now that WPF is open sourced, I logged a bug and planning on fixing this soon: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been working with MediaElement quite few times, and I can honestly say it's a piece of shit and has more bugs than any other WPF component I've encountered. Not only has it bugs, but it's lacking a lot of features that Silverlight has. HTTPS works with Silverlight.

I went through code and I did not see the way to change it. Perhaps there is some MAD reflection hack which would allow you to do it, but that's hacking and I don't recommend that. Ps, it seems like a genuine bug, perhaps let the Microsoft guys know about it.

The easiest solution would be to make a "memory webserver" using OWIN. You can then stream through `http://localhost:1337` and wrap the underlying https:// content. The https content would still be safe though, since you are streaming it from "memory webserver" and no "real" webrequests are ever made. It should still be efficient & secure.

Comment: Thank you, I did that: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/934355/in-a-wpf-standalone-application-exe-when-the-source-of-a-mediaelement-is-set-to-a-https-uri-it-throws-a-nullreferenceexception. Will see what happens. Your idea is interesting, if we can't solve the issue on the servers we may try this.

Comment: @Erti-Chris Eelmaa, can you please attach some example source code of OWIN using to "wrap the underlying https:// content"?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? Maybe can you explain how to make a "memory webserver" to get a http url?