# Workaround to play HTTPS video URL in WPF MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, https, rtsp, mediaelement

I have a C#/WPF application and I need to play a video stream over HTTPS (I'm talking about a YouTube videos, direct URLs extracted by using [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode)).

It's well known that WPF `MediaElement` is a control with a lot of BUGs, but I'm looking for a method to make it work.

Like in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081956/how-to-make-a-wpf-mediaelement-play-when-its-source-is-a-https-uri/25114014), I'd like to make a localhost redirect by coding a small HttpListener that transmits the HTTPS response in real time using an HTTP URL, but I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe someone can help me by making a working example?

Thanks.